# How to move a program to a directory in my PATH

Tags: command-line, pipeline, acquia

Am on a MAC OS following instructions to setup an application(pipelines), and ran the following commands:

```
curl -o pipelines https://cloud.acquia.com/pipeline-client/download
chmod a+x pipelines
```

To finalise the instruction, quoting the guide, I need to move the pipelines program to a directory in my PATH.

How do I move the pipelines program to a directory in my PATH?

Not sure if it helps, but I use zhrc and iterm.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS @TobiasS.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, try opening System Properties => Environment Variables
In the Environment Variables window there should be a variable called Path.
Click it and then click Edit
Then click New on the right hand side and add the path to the program
EXP "C:/User/bin/php.exe"